# Python: Accessing individual values in a dictionary of a list of tuples

Tags: python, dictionary, tuples

I have a dictionary in Python where each key has a set of ten tuples. I am trying to iterate through the dictionary access the individual elements within each tuple- how should I go about that?

The dictionary looks like this:

```
    {'Key1': [(Hi, 1), (Bye, 2)], 'Key2': [(Cats, Blue), (Dogs, Red)]}
```

Say I want vectors of the Keys, a vectors of the first elements [Hi, Bye, Cats, Dogs] and one of the second [1,2, Blue, red]

This is the code I was attempting:

```
    for key in dict:
        for tuplelist in dict:
             key_vector.append(key_
             tuple1_vector.append(dict[key[1]])
             tuple2_vector.append(dict[key[2]])
```

I know this is incorrect but I am not sure how to go about fixing it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume you mean your dict is:

```
your_dict = {'Key1': [('Hi', 1), ('Bye', 2)], 'Key2': [('Cats', 'Blue'), ('Dogs', 'Red')]}
```

You can iterate over all the keys, get whatever tuple is in there, and then iterate over all the entries inside that tuple. There probably is an easier way but this should at least get you there:

```
for key in your_dict:
    for t in your_dict[key]:
        for i in t:
            print(i)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.values()` to access the  values in the dictionary, then iterate over the values lists and index the respective items in the tuple:

```
tuple1_vector = []
tuple2_vector = []
for v in d.values():
    for t in v:
        tuple1_vector.append(t[0])
        tuple2_vector.append(t[1])
```

You can also do this with a list comprehension:

```
tuple1_vector = [t[0]  for v in d.values() for t in v]
tuple2_vector = [t[1]  for v in d.values() for t in v]

print(tuple1_vector)
# ['Cats', 'Dogs', 'Hi', 'Bye']
print(tuple2_vector)
# ['Blue', 'Red', 1, 2]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do the following:

```
keys = []
tuple1 = []
tuple2 = []
for key in dict:
    keys.append(key)
    tuple1.append(dict[key][0][0])
    tuple1.append(dict[key][0][1])
    tuple1.append(dict[key][1][0])
    tuple1.append(dict[key][1][1])
```

But **do not**, this is really bad code. I'm just showing a solution but that's not worth it. The other guys have made it better (such as iterating over dict[key] (e.g. for item in dict[key]...) .